# Progress / 4GL: Export table as .csv with column names and double quotes?

Tags: r, csv, odbc, progress-4gl

I'm trying to write a .p script that will export a table from a database as a csv. The following code creates the csv:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE ("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.csv").

FOR EACH table-name NO-LOCK:
    EXPORT DELIMITER "," table-name.
END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
QUIT.
```

However, I can't figure how to encapsulate all of the fields with double quotes. Nor can I figure out how to get the first row of the .csv to have the column names of the table. How would one go about doing this?

I'm very new to Progress / 4GL. Originally I was using R and an ODBC connection to import and format the table before saving it as a csv. But I've learned that the ODBC driver I'm using does not work reliably...sometimes it will not return all the rows in the table.

The ultimate goal is to pass an argument (table-name) to a .p script that will export the table as a csv. Then I can import the csv in R, manipulate / format the data and then export the table again as a csv.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

- The version of Progress I am using is 9.1D
- Using the above code, the output might look like this...

  ```
  "ACME",01,"Some note that may contain carriage returns.\n More text",yes,"01A"
  ```
- The reason for trying to encapsulate every field with double quotes is because some fields may contain carriage returns or other special characters. R doesn't always like carriage return in the middle of field. So the desired output would be...

  ```
  "ACME","01","Some note that may contain carriage returns.\n More text","yes","01A"
  ```

Comment: Holy cow 9.1D is beyond ancient.... so much for most of the more elegant solutions :-) Wouldn't you rather get rid of the carriage returns?

Comment: @TheMadDBA I currently have an R script that removes any 'special characters' using gsub. But if I could find and replace any of these 'special characters' before exporting the csv that might be a much better way of solving the problem!

Comment: Give the new version a try in the edited answer. If you have a list of ascii character values to replace it should be easy to modify.

Answer (score 2):

Progress version is important to know. Your ODBC issue is likely caused by the fact that formats in Progress are default display formats and don't actually limit the amount of data to be stored. Which of course drives SQL mad.

You can use this KB to learn about the DBTool utility to fix the SQL width http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496

As far as the export is concerned what you are doing will already take care of the double quotes for character columns. You have a few options to solve your header issue depending on your version of Progress. This one will work no matter your version but is not as elegant as the newer options....

Basically copy this into the procedure editor and it will generate a program with internal procedures for each table in your DB. Run the csvdump.p by passing in the table name and the csv file you want( run csvdump.p ("mytable","myfile").

Disclaimer you may run into some odd datatypes that can't be exported like RAW but they aren't very common.

```
DEF VAR i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

OUTPUT TO csvdump.p.

PUT UNFORMATTED 
    "define input parameter ipTable as character no-undo." SKIP
    "define input parameter ipFile  as character no-undo." SKIP(1)
    "OUTPUT TO VALUE(ipFile)." SKIP(1)
    "RUN VALUE('ip_' + ipTable)." SKIP(1)
    "OUTPUT CLOSE." SKIP(1).

FOR EACH _file WHERE _file._tbl-type = "T" NO-LOCK:

    PUT UNFORMATTED "PROCEDURE ip_" _file._file-name ":" SKIP(1)
                    "EXPORT DELIMITER "~",~"" SKIP.

    FOR EACH _field OF _File NO-LOCK BY _Field._Order:

      IF _Field._Extent = 0 THEN
         PUT UNFORMATTED "~"" _Field-Name "~"" SKIP.
      ELSE DO i = 1 TO _Field._Extent:
          PUT UNFORMATTED "~"" _Field-Name STRING(i,"999") "~"" SKIP.
      END.
    END.

    PUT UNFORMATTED "." SKIP(1)
                    "FOR EACH " _File._File-name " NO-LOCK:" SKIP
                    "    EXPORT DELIMITER "~",~" " _File._File-Name "." SKIP
                    "END." SKIP(1).

    PUT UNFORMATTED "END PROCEDURE." SKIP(1).

END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

BIG Disclaimer.... I don't have 9.1D to test with since it is well past the supported date.... I believe all of this will work though.

There are other ways to do this even in 9.1D (dynamic queries) but this will probably be easier for you to modify if needed since you are new to Progress. Plus it is likely to perform better than purely dynamic exports. You can keep nesting the REPLACE functions to get rid of more and more characters... or just copy the replace line and let it run it over and over if needed.

```
DEF VAR i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

FUNCTION fn_Export RETURNS CHARACTER (INPUT ipExtent AS INTEGER):
  IF _Field._Data-Type = "CHARACTER" THEN
    PUT UNFORMATTED "fn_Trim(".

  PUT UNFORMATTED _File._File-Name "." _Field._Field-Name.

  IF ipExtent > 0 THEN
    PUT UNFORMATTED "[" STRING(ipExtent) "]" SKIP.

  IF _Field._Data-Type = "CHARACTER" THEN
    PUT UNFORMATTED ")".

  PUT UNFORMATTED SKIP.

END.

OUTPUT TO c:\temp\wks.p.

PUT UNFORMATTED 
    "define input parameter ipTable as character no-undo." SKIP
    "define input parameter ipFile  as character no-undo." SKIP(1)

    "function fn_Trim returns character (input ipChar as character):" SKIP
    "   define variable cTemp as character no-undo." SKIP(1)
    "   if ipChar = '' or ipChar = ? then return ipChar." SKIP(1)
    "   cTemp = replace(replace(ipChar,CHR(13),''),CHR(11),'')." SKIP(1)
    "   return cTemp." SKIP(1)
    "end." SKIP(1)

    "OUTPUT TO VALUE(ipFile)." SKIP(1)
    "RUN VALUE('ip_' + ipTable)." SKIP(1)
    "OUTPUT CLOSE." SKIP(1).

FOR EACH _file WHERE _file._tbl-type = "T" NO-LOCK:

    PUT UNFORMATTED "PROCEDURE ip_" _file._file-name ":" SKIP(1)
                    "EXPORT DELIMITER "~",~"" SKIP.

    FOR EACH _field OF _File NO-LOCK BY _Field._Order:

      IF _Field._Extent = 0 THEN
         PUT UNFORMATTED "~"" _Field-Name "~"" SKIP.
      ELSE DO i = 1 TO _Field._Extent:
          PUT UNFORMATTED "~"" _Field-Name STRING(i) "~"" SKIP.
      END.
    END.

    PUT UNFORMATTED "." SKIP(1)
                    "FOR EACH " _File._File-name " NO-LOCK:" SKIP.

    PUT UNFORMATTED "EXPORT DELIMITER ~",~"" SKIP.

    FOR EACH _field OF _File NO-LOCK BY _Field._Order:

      IF _Field._Extent = 0 OR _Field._Extent = ? THEN 
         fn_Export(0).

      ELSE DO i = 1 TO _Field._Extent:
         fn_Export(i).
      END.
    END.

    PUT UNFORMATTED "." SKIP(1)
                    "END." SKIP(1).

    PUT UNFORMATTED "END PROCEDURE." SKIP(1).

END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

I beg to differ on one small point with @TheMadDBA.  using EXPORT will *not* deal with quoting all the fields in your output in CSV style.  Logical fields, for example, will not be quoted.

'CSV Format' is the vaguest of standards, but the export command does not conform with it. It was not designed for that.  (I notice that in @TheMadDBA's final example, they do not use export, either.)

If you want all the non-numeric fields quoted, you need to handle this yourself.

```
def stream s.
output stream s to value(v-filename).

for each tablename no-lock:  
    put stream s unformatted
            '"' tablename.charfield1 '"'
            ',' string(tablename.numfield)
            ',"' tablename.charfield2 '"'
            skip.
end.

output stream s close.
```

In this example I'm assuming that you are okay with coding a specific dump for a single table, rather than a generic solution.  You can certainly do the latter with meta-programming as in @TheMadDBA's answer, with ABL's dynamic query syntax, or even with -- may the gods forgive us both -- include files.  But that's a more advanced topic, and you said you were just starting with ABL.

You will still have to deal with string truncation as per @TheMadDBAs answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some inspiration from @TheMadDBAs and additional thought here is my solution to the problem...

I decided to write a script in R that would generate the p scripts. The R script uses one input, the table name and dumps out the p script.

Below is a sample p script...

```
DEFINE VAR columnNames AS CHARACTER.
columnNames = """" + "Company" + """" + "|" + """" + "ABCCode" + """" + "|" + """" + "MinDollarVolume" + """" + "|" + """" + "MinUnitCost" + """" + "|" + """" + "CountFreq" + """".

/* Define the temp-table */

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tempTable
    FIELD tCompany AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tABCCode AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tMinDollarVolume AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tMinUnitCost AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tCountFreq AS CHARACTER.


FOR EACH ABCCode NO-LOCK:
    CREATE tempTable.
    tempTable.tCompany = STRING(Company).
    tempTable.tABCCode = STRING(ABCCode).
    tempTable.tMinDollarVolume = STRING(MinDollarVolume).
    tempTable.tMinUnitCost = STRING(MinUnitCost).
    tempTable.tCountFreq = STRING(CountFreq).
END.


OUTPUT TO VALUE ("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ABCCode.csv").

/* Output the column names */

PUT UNFORMATTED columnNames.
PUT UNFORMATTED "" SKIP.

/* Output the temp-table */

FOR EACH tempTable NO-LOCK:
    EXPORT DELIMITER "|" tempTable.
END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.

QUIT.

/* Done */
```

The R script makes an ODBC call to the DB to get the column names for the table of interest and then populates the template to generate the p script.

I'm not sure creating a temp table and casting everything as a character is the best way of solving the problem, but...

- we have column names
- everything is encapsulated in double quotes
- and we can choose any delimiter (e.g. "|" instead of ",")